# Printing floating-point GPA in C++

Tags: c++, printing, floating-point

my problem is when I am trying to print a floating-point GPA in C++.

It seems like a simple issue, but I can't get it to work. Basically I have a floating point value set to 4.0 for a GPA. However, when I try to print it like this:

```
cout << gpa << endl;
```

I get the value of 4. Without the .0 on the end. However, I want the .0 to show up. I have tried setting a precision but with no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Lol - I know how to do this with printf, but not cout.  Too much C for me I guess.  I know it's a formatting issue.

Comment: I know, I can do the same with printf, but I cannot figure it out with cout. Very frustrating!

Comment: Above is a link this should help.

Comment: Search SO and the web for "cout floating point precision".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::fixed` in conjunction with `std::setprecision`

```
#include <iostream> // std::fixed
#include <iomanip> // std::setprecision

int main() {
  double gpa = 4.0;
  std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << gpa << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

// Output is 4.0
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Just needed the fixed-point notation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include <iomanip>
    ...
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);                                  // use fixed-point notation
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);                              // show decimal point
    cout.precision(1);
    ...
    cout << gpa << endl;
```